# Check if a certain user has a certain attribute from a imported CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following shutdown script:

```
    Stop-Process -ProcessName Thunderbird* -Force -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue' 
Stop-Process -ProcessName Outlook* -Force -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue'
$personname= ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:userdomain/$env:username,user").fullname 
$res=Test-Path "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" 
if ($res -eq $False) 
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" 

    Import-Csv \\cd2012\backup\lista.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -Header Name,User,Attribute

                if  ($_.Attribute -ne "T" -and $_.User -eq $env:username) 
                    {
                        & c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\" "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA 
                    } 
                else
                    {
                        & c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "$env:APPDATA\Thunderbird\Profiles\" "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA 

                    }
                Set-ItemProperty -Path "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" -Name LastWriteTime -Value $(Get-Date)  





}
else
{
    $wts=Get-Item "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}  

        if ($wts -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(2)) 
        {
                Import-Csv \\cd2012\backup\lista.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -Header Name,User,Attribute

                if  ($_.Attribute -ne "T" -and $_.User -eq $env:username) 
                    {
                        & c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Outlook\" "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA 
                    } 
                else
                    {
                        & c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "$env:APPDATA\Thunderbird\Profiles\" "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA 

                    }
                Set-ItemProperty -Path "\\cd2012\backup\$personname" -Name LastWriteTime -Value $(Get-Date)  


          }

}
```

The CSV file contains the following

Bob;User1;

John;User2;

Mike;User3;T

George:User4;T

This script basically makes backup copies of folders every 2 days. The issue I am having is checking the username and attribute when it comes to deciding if the client has Outlook or Thunderbird. If the user has the "T" attribute, I know he has Thunderbird, so I should copy from the Thunderbird location. If he does not, I should copy from the Outlook location.

I know all my clients have the same default location because I am the only the configures it.

Comment: You have problems parsing the T attribute?

Comment: I am not sure where the issue is in the script. It works great for Outlook users but It is not working right now for Thunderbird. Basically, it does not enter the condition where it is Thunderbird so you might be right that it is having issues with the T attribute...

Comment: I think you could script that MUCH simpler if you just check whether '$env:APPDATA\Thunderbird\Profiles\' exists?

Comment: @jisaak Also a good idea....I want to make the script as univeral possible (to avoid code rot if something is changed in the future) but at the same time, simple and quick.to write. Difficult I know

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your script to something like this:

```
Stop-Process -ProcessName Thunderbird* -Force -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue' 
Stop-Process -ProcessName Outlook* -Force -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue'

$personname= ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:userdomain/$env:username,user").fullname 

$robocopyExe = join-Path $env:windir 'system32\Robocopy.exe'
$backupFolder = Join-Path '\\cd2012\backup\' $personname

# ensure the backup target is present
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $backupFolder -Force | out-null

$thunderbirdDir = Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'Thunderbird\Profiles'
$outlookDir = Join-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA 'Microsoft\Outlook'

if (Test-Path $thunderbirdDir)
{
    & $robocopyExe $thunderbirdDir $backupFolder /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA /minage:2
}
if (Test-Path $outlookDir)
{
    & $robocopyExe $outlookDir $backupFolder /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA /minage:2
}
```

Note: The two day copy skip is controlled using  [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc733145(v=WS.10).aspx) **/minage** Parameter.

Comment: I understand SOME parts of your script....Is there anything wrong with my version, even if it is longer?

Comment: You have problems with your T attribute, this script doesnt use it.